# Iterate through a list of DataFrame column names and add only the column names whose values are integers or floats to a new list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, imputation

Here is a snapshot of the dataframe:
[image: DataFrame]

Here is the code I have attempted to run:

The first list contains the column names of all the entries where there is empty/NaN values

**cols_missing_values = [col for col in X1_train.columns if X1_train[col].isnull().any()]**

Below is my attempt at a List Comprehension to create a new list that contains only the column names whose data types are either integers or floats.

**cols_missing_values_numbers = [col for col in cols_missing_values if X1_train.dtypes is type == int or float]
cols_missing_values_numbers**

This is the current error I get: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Overall what I am trying to do is find the column names in the DataFrame where I can use Imputation. I was going to drop the columns who have empty or missing values but have categorical data in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'int_col': [1, 2, 3], 
     'float_col': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], 
     'obj_col': list('abc')})

>>> [col for col in df if df[col].dtype in [np.dtype(t) for t in ('int', 'float')]]
['int_col', 'float_col']
```

To add the null condition on the columns:

```
cols_missing_values_numbers = [
    col for col in df 
    if df[col].dtype in [np.dtype(t) for t in ('int', 'float')] 
    and df[col].isnull().any()
]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Could you explain what the second list in the comprehension does (the numpy bit). Thanks

Comment: It is equivalent to `[np.dtype('int'), np.dtype('float')]`, but easier to generalize if you want to use different types as you just have a list of them, e.g. `('int', 'float')`. Also, the following expression evaluates to `True`: `np.int64 == np.dtype('int')`.